# Android gradle uploadArchives when building

Tags: android, maven, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have my `uploadArhives` to Maven repository `.aar` publishing.

But I have to run `gradlew uploadArhives` from the console all the time, how to code to make it invoke with every build or with release build?

```
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            def credentials = [
                    userName: NEXUS_USERNAME,
                    password: NEXUS_PASSWORD
            ]
            repository(url: MAVEN_REPO_URL, authentication: credentials)
            pom.artifactId = 'aaa'
            pom.version = version
            pom.packaging = 'aar'
            pom.groupId = 'bbb'

        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

As I think, we can define function:

```
def uploadToMaven = {
    uploadArchives
}
```

But how to execute it with every build?

Comment: Have you thought about creating a travis.ci or another sort of build automation script (.sh file)?  Surely gradlew or another terminal tool has an option for building the app. From there it's as simple as running your build script each time you want to perform these actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a complex project with many modules and one main application.
I added "uploadArchives" on two of these modules (because are android libraries). In this way I can publish my libraries on Maven simply running the task uploadArchives from my main application, or using gradle and calling this task "uploadArchives".

You can use this in your build.gradle (of the library that you want to publish) "build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)".

For example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }


}


build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = "2.8"
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':spfshared')
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
}

//task for Sonatype Nexus OSS
uploadArchives {
    repositories {
        mavenDeployer {
            repository(
                    url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/releases") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }
            snapshotRepository(
                    url: "${nexusUrl}/content/repositories/snapshots") {
                authentication(userName: nexusUsername, password: nexusPassword)
            }

            pom.version = "2.0.0.1"
            pom.artifactId = "spflib"
            pom.groupId = "it.polimi.spf"
        }
    }
}
```

After every build, uploadArchives will starts.

I tried this solution and it works.

I also tried some solutions with "build.dependsOn myTaskName" without success. If you want you can try, but on my AndroidStudio, the first solution it works.

PS: I tested my solution using the command "gradlew -q build" and also running specifically the task "build" from my main module in Android Studio (that it's my main application).

If you want to call "uploadArchives" at every release, simply replace "build" with the release task.

**Update:**
I tried also with these codelines:

```
defaultTasks 'uploadArchives'

clean.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)
assembleDebug.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)
assembleRelease.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)
```

But sometimes they call "uploadArchives" many times and I think that it's not a good idea.

What you are asking is very challenging... I tried for an entire hour :)

Comment: Yes, this works great! But it is working when I type "gradlew -q build".
How can I upload artifacts with every build? When I press build or Run button?

Comment: So `gradlew -q build` worth typing 'gradlew uploadArhives'

Comment: Yes, this update code really works, thank you! It would be great also if you share link with documentation, because it was hard for me to find it.

Comment: Thank u. I'm sorry but i've not used a website with documentation to do that. I tried many many times randomly XD For this reason I said that : "it's not a good idea", because it's not an official solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just add this line to your build.gradle:

```
build.finalizedBy(uploadArchives)
```

This creates a task dependency between build task and uploadArchives task, such that uploadArchives is automatically called everytime build executes successfully.

Comment: And where to place it?
I tried in `afterEvaluate { project ->` but that don't help

Comment: Try just placing it at the root level of your build.gradle?

Comment: I tried to place it everywhere possible in gradle file, in root too.

Comment: I overlooked that you're asking for an android project. Is your `uploadArchives` task in your root build.gradle?